# Random Forest Classification - SciKit vs Weka on prediction with 100 features

Tags: weka, scikit-learn, random-forest

I wanted to get a much faster random forest classifier than the one from Weka, I first tried the C++ Shark implementation (results: few speed improvement, drop in correctly classifed instances) and then tested Python Scikit-learn. I read on many websites and papers that Weka performs badly compared to Scikit, WiseRF...

After my first try with a forest of 100 trees:

```
Training time: Weka  ~ 170s VS Scikit ~ 31s
Prediction results on the same test set: Weka ~ 90% correctly classified VS Scikit score ~ 45% !!!
```

=> Scikit RF runs fast but classify very badly on this first try.

I tuned the parameters of Scikit RandomForestClassifier and  managed to get a score close to 70% but the speed of scikit dropped nearly down to Weka performance (bootstrap=False, min_samples_leaf=3, min_samples_split=1, criterion='entropy', max_features=40, max_depth=6). I do have many missing values and scikit does not handle them out of the box so I tried many different strategies (all strategies of Imputer, skip instances with missing values, replace with 0 or extreme values) and reached 75%.

So at this stage Scikit RandomForestClassifier performs at 75% (compared to 90% with weka) and build the model in 78s (using 6 cores vs 170s with only 1 core with Weka). I am very surprised with those results. I tested ExtraTrees which performs very well in terms of speed but still reach an average of 75% correct classification.

Do you have any idea what I am missing ?

My data: ~100 features, ~100 000 instances, missing values, classification prediction (price forecast).

Comment: Is this a regression or a classification problem? Intuitively price forecasting sounds like a regression but you are talking about stuff like "90% correctly classified". What kind of scoring metrics do you use?

Comment: It is a classification problem as prices are from a rates list. Scoring metrics used are simply: total correctly classified / total instances. I really don't understand how Random Forest could perform far better on Weka in terms of accuracy? My first guess is that Weka would handle missing values better than any Scikit missing values strategy but I also tried to skip any instance with missing values but I only reached 77% (still far from weka's 90%).

Comment: It could be the missing value handling. Or are some of the features categorical or are they all purely numerical? If you have categorical features, what are their cardinality? Have you tried to one-hot encode them or do you use an integer encoding for those?

Comment: @ogrisel The output is categorical but are numeric values: a list of possible prices/rates. Ok, I will try to one-hot encode them instead.

Comment: I meant one-hot-encoding the input, not the output. Depending on the cardinality, it might or might not be better to use the one-hot encoding of categorical features in random forests.

Comment: That's been a while since your last comment, sorry. I ended up using weka for various reasons but I was able to reach comparable results using scikit RF with optimal parameters (GridSearchCV) and most of all by ignoring all cases with missing values. Thanks a lot for your help.

PS: of course I didn't use one-hot-encoding on outputs, I used it on inputs but it did not really change the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Which hyper-parameters did you have to grid search to reach acceptable accuracy in this case? `criterion`, `max_features`, `max_depth`, `min_samples_split`?

Comment: Optimal parameters obtained: _bootstrap_ => True _min_samples_leaf_ => 3 _min_samples_split_ => 2 _criterion_ => 'entropy' _max_features_ => None _max_depth_ => 7

Comment: Please also note that Scikit ExtraTrees ran much faster than RF and also obtained similar classification perfomance

Comment: About speed, Weka random forest also works with multiple cores, to use 6, just use forest.setNumExecutionSlots(6), that will speed up weka Random Forest considerably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping up the discussion in the comments to make StackOverflow mark this question as answered:

Apparently OP was able to reach comparable of accuracy by dropping samples with missing values and grid searching optimal hyper-parameter values with `GridSearchCV`.

One-hot-encoding categorical features was apparently not impacting the outcome much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a huge performance difference from the Weka and Scikit-learn Random Forest implementations with the same data and the same configuration(?). After trying all possible solutions, I noticed that it was actually pretty straightforward. Weka shuffles the data in default but Scikit-learn does not. Even after setting Weka's configuration option: use the data as ordered, it is still the same. So, here is how I handled it. Use the random_state=1 (it is the default in Weka), shuffle=True in Scikit-learn for cross-validator, bootstrap=True in classifier. It produces quite the similar results with Weka. E.g.

```
classifier = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=300,  max_depth=30, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=1, random_state=1, bootstrap=True, criterion='entropy', n_jobs=-1)

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=num_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(classifier, param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv)
```